# Absolute element becomes fixed when vertical scrolling past it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently making a website of my own based on HTML, CSS and a tiny bit of Javascript/jQuery. (I'm bad with JavaScript. Never really tried to learn it, just copied codes off.)

I'm trying to have my navigation bar or "table des matières" (site is in french), which is a `position: absolute;` element, become a `position: fixed;` element once you scroll past it, something like [plus.google.com](http://plus.google.com) (Google+'s sub-header).

Here is my code so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FnCch

I just don't see how to make it happen.

Also, I would like some insight on how I can make my page look better. I'm trying a full-page design, something like Apple's, instead of the usual margin and table-like site.
My brother said the effects and the coding was amazing but that it looked disgusting (badly aligned, I'm having trouble with that, fonts don't go well with each other, he says everything is way too big... etc)

http://remyses.neocities.org/tpe2014.html

Comment: Try http://ux.stackexchange.com/ for design advice.

Comment: Just a word of warning, avoid using massive images when possible, especially more than one at once. These can really slow down browsing, both in terms of loading the page and scrolling down it. (You have a couple on your page that are thousands of pixels in width/height.)

Comment: I used those high resolution images since I had my google free-of-copyright search tools on 4K (for my desktop's), but up until now it hasn't slowed too much. I will however abstain from using that big of an image in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following javascript to change the styling of the nav bar when you scroll the window down.

```
// trigger on scroll event    
window.onscroll = function () {
  // get scrollbar position
  var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
  var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);

  // get menu 
  var menu = document.getElementById("cssmenu");

  // if scrollbar past menu height: set position to fixed, 
  if (top > (menu.offsetHeight + menu.offsetTop)) {
     menu.style.position = "fixed";
  } 
  // set position to absolute
  else {
     menu.style.position = "absolute"; 
  }
};
```

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xnsBC

Comment: Many thanks really! I added the other settings I wanted, javascript may actually not be as hard as I thought! It works fanstastically!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, bootstrap is an awesome framework to get things going with the proper JS to make anything you want adaptive for different devices. From the design aspect you might also want to use EMs for fonts instead of px so they will be easier to read on all devices as well.

Also within bootstrap there is a plugin called affix for exactly what you are trying to do:
[Link to Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Answer (score 0):

For styling, without tables you can use div tags. CSS frameworks like bootstraps are also very helpful. For the navigation bar to stay, you will have to make it position:fixed instead of position:absolute. If you want the use to scroll the page, then the nav bar stay at the top of the screen, you would need some javascript.